# N closest points to the reference point

Tags: c++, c++11, coordinate-system, clustering

Here is working code to get N closest points to some reference point.

Please help to improve it, specifically by commenting on my use of `std` algorithms and vectors/iterators manipulations.

**Nearest.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

namespace nearest {

struct Point {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;

  bool operator==(const Point& rhp) {
    return x == rhp.x && y == rhp.y && z == rhp.z;
  }

};

// Return N closest points to first point in vector in order
std::vector<Point> nearestN(const std::vector<Point>& points,
                            int N);


// Return N closest points to a reference point, in order - all
// within maximum distance threshold
std::vector<Point> nearestN(const std::vector<Point>& points,
                            int N,
                            const Point& reference,
                            double distanceThreshold);

}
```

**Nearest.cpp**

```
#include "Nearest.h"

using namespace std;

namespace nearest {

    // to print Point to cout
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &o, const nearest::Point& p) {
        o << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ", " << p.z << ")" << std::endl;
        return o;
    }

    // defines sorting order for points
    struct ByDistance {
        const Point& origin;

        bool operator()(const Point& lp, const Point& rp) {
            return dist(origin, lp) < dist(origin, rp);
        }

        static double dist(const Point& lp, const Point& rp){
            double xs = (lp.x - rp.x) * (lp.x - rp.x);
            double ys = (lp.y - rp.y) * (lp.y - rp.y);
            double zs = (lp.z - rp.z) * (lp.z - rp.z);
            return sqrt(xs + ys + zs);
        }
    };

    vector<Point> nearestN(const vector<Point>& points, int N) {
        if (points.size() == 0) {
            vector<Point> empty;
            return empty;
        }
        return nearestN(points, N, points[0], INFINITY);
    }

    vector<Point> nearestN(const vector<Point>& points,
                           int N,
                           const Point& reference,
                           double distanceThreshold) {

        vector<Point> temp;
        temp.insert(temp.begin(), points.begin(), points.end());

        // filtering vector to remove all points far then distance from reference
        temp.erase(remove_if(temp.begin(), 
                             temp.end(),
                             [&reference, distanceThreshold](Point& p){ return ByDistance::dist(p, reference) > distanceThreshold; }),
                   temp.end());

        ByDistance distance = {reference};
        sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), distance);

        auto sz = min(static_cast<int>(temp.size()), N);
        vector<Point> result(sz);
        copy_n(temp.begin(), sz, result.begin());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many points are usually in your input? If it's a lot and you find this code getting to be too slow, you might look into using something like a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. A comparison-function doesn't change either argument, so should take them by `const&`.
2. You normally don't make comparison-operators member-functions to make sure they handle conversions equally for both arguments.
   If neccessary, that might mean making them `friend`-functions, whether defined inline or not.
3. If you provide `==`, you should also provide `!=`:

   They model *one* concept, which can be trivially implemented in terms of each other (so much one wonders why the language does not implicitly define the second, with explicit overriding for *strange* types like floating-point), and everyone expects there to be both or none.
4. Consider naming your type `Point3` to clarify that this is the 3d-point-variant.

   ```
    struct Point3
    {
        double x, y, z;
    };
    bool operator==(const Point3& a, const Point3& b) {
        return a.x==b.x && a.y==b.y && a.z==b.z;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Point3& a, const Point3& b) { return !(a==b); }
   ```
5. Don't ask for `size()` if all you want to know is whether a container is `empty()`. While there is no performance-difference for `std::vector`, there is one for other containers. Also, the latter is more explicit.
6. `nearestN` is severely sub-par:

   - Use squared distances to avoid the costly square-roots.
   - Don't create copies you don't need.
   - Just like there's an algorithm for removing elements fulfilling a predicate, there is one for only copying them: `std::copy_if`, coupled with `std::back_inserter`.
   - Anyway, you actually want to build a list of candidates, and then choose the N best.

   ```
   constexpr double distance2(const Point3& a, const Point3& b) {
       return (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x)+(a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)+(a.z-b.z)*(a.z-b.z);
   }

   std::vector<Point3> nearestN(
       const std::vector<Point3>& v,
       int maxN,
       const Point3& center,
       double maxDistance
   ) {
       assert(maxDistance >= 0 && maxN >= 0);
       maxDistance *= maxDistance;
       std::vector<std::pair<double, const Point3*>> temp;
       temp.reserve(v.size());
       for(auto&& x : v) {
           double d = distance2(x, center);
           if(d <= maxDistance)
               temp.emplace_back(d, &x);
       }
       if(maxN >= temp.size())
           maxN = temp.size();
       else
           std::sort(begin(temp), end(temp));
       std::vector<Point3> r;
       r.reserve(maxN);
       for(size_t i = 0; i < maxN; ++i)
           r.push_back(*temp[i].second);
       return r;
   }
   ```
7. Using a heap (`std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap`), you can keep the list of candidates minimal and thus reduce the complexity to O(n*log(min(n, N))) (n=elements in input, N=max elements in output.
   [I used a custom `replace_heap`](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85981f0c896526a5) (equivalent to popping the head and then pushing a replacement) adapted from [How to replace top element of heap efficiently withouth re-establishing heap invariant twice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/32672474) for even more efficiency:

   ```
   std::vector<Point3> nearestN(
       const std::vector<Point3>& v,
       std::size_t maxN,
       const Point3& center,
       double maxDistance
   ) {
       assert(maxDistance >= 0);
       if(maxN <= 0) return {};
       maxDistance *= maxDistance;
       if(std::isinf(maxDistance) && v.size() <= maxN) return v;
       using pair = std::pair<double, const Point3*>;
       std::unique_ptr<pair[]> heap{new pair[maxN]};
       size_t N = 0, i = v.size();
       while(i && N < maxN) {
           double d = distance2(center, v[--i]);
           if(d <= maxDistance)
               heap[N++] = {d, &v[i]};
       }
       if(i)
           std::make_heap(heap.get(), heap.get() + N);
       while(i) {
           double d = distance2(center, v[--i]);
           if(d < heap[0].first) {
               heap[0] = {d, &v[i]};
               replace_heap(&heap[0], &heap[N]);
           }
       }
       std::vector<Point3> r;
       r.reserve(N);
       for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
           r.push_back(*heap[i].second);
       return r;
   }
   ```
8. Prefer a `std::span<const T>` over a `std::vector<T> const&`. Less indirection and potentially cheaper construction lead to more efficiency.

   Even though it was only standardised with C++20, there are plenty implementations for even C++11.
   See "[What is a “span” and when should I use one?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45723819)" for more details.

Answer (score 11):

## Faster sorting

If the only purpose of the distance computation is for comparison, then you can speed it up by removing the call to `sqrt()`.  You'll end up comparing the squares of the distances, which is equivalent to comparing the actual distances.

Answer (score 10):

- `ByDistance` looks very ad-hoc. If you move `dist` to `Point` (where it really belongs) as a member function, `ByDistance` is not required at all, e.g:

  ```
      temp.erase(remove_if(temp.begin(), 
                       temp.end(),
                       [&reference, distanceThreshold](Point& p){
                           return reference.dist(p > distanceThreshold;
                       }),
             temp.end());
  ```

  and

  ```
      sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(),
          [&reference](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
              return reference.dist(p1) < reference.dist(p2);
          });
      );
  ```
- I don't see a need to create yet another `vector` with

  ```
      vector<Point> result(sz);
  ```

  You may reuse `temp` with `temp.resize()` instead.
- Mandatory advisory against [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Are you missing a close paren in that first code block? Something doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Free functions should generally be preferred, especially if the public interface suffices to implement them. That counts double for functions symmetric in their arguments.

Answer (score 10):

- Your operator overloads (`operator==` and `operator()`) should be `const` since they don't modify any data members.
- `operator<<` can just be a single line.  It could also use `"\n"` instead of `std::endl` so that one isn't forced to have a buffer flush when invoking it ([there is a different between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)).

  ```
  return o << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ", " << p.z << ")\n";
  ```
- This can be shortened:

  > ```
  > if (points.size() == 0) {
  >     vector<Point> empty;
  >     return empty;
  > }
  > ```

  by using `empty()` and by returning an anonymous `vector` instead:

  ```
  if (points.empty()) {
      return vector<Point>();
  }
  ```